# How can I improve my "newname" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a student and I got the memo (without explanation) that
my following code is bugged and can be much better. How would you improve my `controller#newname` method? Thank you for your time!

```
class ReviewController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @reviews = Review.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end

    def newname
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
        if @review.update_attribute(:title, sanitize(params[:title]))
            format.json { render json: { status: 200 } }
        else
            format.json { render json: { status: 500 } }
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Where's the reviewname method?

Comment: @locoboy sorry i meant the newname method

Comment: First step is to rename `newname` method to `update`. This would align more with REST best practices rather than having a custom route that is not intuitive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a clear request for a code review. We have a SE site for code reviews.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest flaw is that `update_attribute` skips all the validations, hence, your else statement will rarely/never be executed. Change it to:

```
@review.name = sanitize(params[:title])
if @review.save
  #...
```

and it should be much better.

Comment: To complete the answer :
Code 500 is reserved for machine errors, you should use 422 if the resource hasn't updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you could perhaps do something similar to:

```
class ReviewController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @reviews = Review.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end

    def newname
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
        if @review.update(:title => sanitize(params[:title]))
          render json: @review
        else
          render :json => { errors: @review.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
        end
    end

end
```

The idea being to stay 'on the rails' and let the conventions do the work for you.

This addresses the

- status code
- method used to update
- errors

Answer (score 0):

To build upon BroiSatse's answer, I would definitely use save instead of update_attribute. I would also return the errors that occur so the user can parse or show them. If you're on Rails 4, use [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) (declare in a private method in controller)

#### Rails 3:

```
 def newname
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
        @review.title = sanitize(params[:title])
        if @review.save
            format.json { render json: { status: 200 } }
        else
            render :json => {:errors => @review.errors.full_messages}, :status => 422
        end
    end
```

#### Rails 4

```
  class ReviewController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_review, only [:newname] #list additional methods as needed...
    ...
    def newname
        #@review is retrieved from set_review
        if @review.update(review_params)
             format.json { render json: { status: 200 } }
        else
             render :json => {:errors => @review.errors.full_messages}, :status => 422
        end
    end

 private
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:title)
    end
end
```